# cin object in cpp

Tags: c++, object, input

I started to learn cpp and encountered cin as a way to receive input from the keyboard.
If I understood, cin is an object and >> is an operator defined for it.
In the way it is defined, how does it "knows" to separate words from each other?
and another thing, 
what is the meaning of:
while(cin)
is cin a bool type? what does it mean if it returns true or false?

Comment: "In the way it is defined, how does it "knows" to separate words from each other?"
It's not clear what you're asking here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Calling:

```
cin >> var1 >> var2 >> var3;
```

is equivalent to:

```
cin >> var1;
cin >> var2;
cin >> var3;
```

As far as your other question goes, in C/C++ anything that returns a `NULL` or zero is treated as false in an `if` statement, otherwise it is treated as true.

That's why the line: `if(cin)` works to check whether there's more data to be read in the stream.

Comment: Your description of `if(cin)` is not quite the whole truth. One cannot put anything as the condition; is has to be a primitive type, or otherwise "convertible" to one. In the case of std::istream, of which std::cin is an instance, this is done via `operator void*()`. While the stream is "okay", the function returns non-NULL, otherwise it returns NULL.

Answer (score 2):

[cin usage](http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq-lite/input-output.html#faq-15.4)

"Where strm is the identifier of a istream object and variable is an object of any type supported as right parameter. It is also possible to call a succession of extraction operations as:

```
strm >> variable1 >> variable2 >> variable3; //...
```

which is the same as performing successive extractions from the same object strm" -> from 
[operator>>](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/iostream/istream/operator%3E%3E/)

Answer (score 1):

When you use the input stream there are specific character(s) defined to separate items in the input. By default I believe it's the space character. So you can enter things separated by spaces.

Comment: +1 because this explains how cin "knows" how to separate words from an input stream.

Comment: Actually, it uses any whitespace character as delimiter, which includes space, newline, tab, and more. But it's correct that it stops the current extraction when a delimiter is encountered.